# VMware View Connection Server - User not entitled to use system

Tags: active-directory, vmware-view

I've been trying to setup a VMware View connection server. I feel like I am getting it close to having it working, but haven't had success yet. The current issue is that the connection server tells me I am "not entitled" to use the system after logging in with my domain credentials. I don't know why this is the case, because I am explicitly set as an administrator to the system!

So my question is slightly two-fold I guess...

1. Where do user credentials come from? I am assuming they are from Active Directory, since that is what I am prompted to log into a domain.
2. How do I give a user privileges to access the system? I have looked all through the web admin interface of the connection server. There is a section to add users, but when I search for a domain user in here no users are returned. In fact, there are no users at all.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

I guess I have this figured out now...

1. Users come from Active Directory, as I thought.
2. To add entitlements to a user, you must **FIRST** add a desktop source and *then* entitle a user (even a new user) to use the resource. It seems backwards to me, but that's the way it works.